# How to have smooth width change of React component in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React/MUI 5 and I have something like this `<div>{text}</div>` with a custom border style. The `text` is a `string` that initialize and update with `setText`.

At the beginning the `text` is an empty string so the width of `div` is little and when my `text` update, width of `div` increase immediately.
I've tried to set transition CSS property for width to its CSS class but nothing happened.

How can I have a smooth width change in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use Typography built-in MUI Component for the text and pass Component prop if you want to use it as a Div. Here is the link to the mui official typography docs. https://mui.com/customization/typography/